# extraneous key env is not permitted in circle ci

Tags: mysql, circleci, circleci-2.0

in my `circle.yml` I added `env:` header to add my mysql environment variables settings, I saw this in some example online, and it works well and my build pass. but I get this warning:

[image]

this is how it looks like in my `circle.yml`

```
docker:
  - image: elasticsearch:1.3.9
  - image: circleci/mysql:5.6
    env:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=MyDB
environment:
  SBT_VERSION: 1.1.0
  SBT_OPTS: "-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M"
.....
```

Did anyone had this before?

Answer (score 6):

*disclaimer: CircleCI Developer Advocate*

There's a few issues here. This is not a bug. The wrong key is being used.

1. This is a `.circleci/config.yml` snippet not `circle.yml` The former is CircleCI 2.0 and the latter is CircleCI 1.0.
2. The key used shouldn't be `env` but `environment`, just like what you use a few lines after.
3. The syntax for the variables isn't wrong in this case but using a key and value syntax can be better in some scenarios.

Here's what the config should look like:

```
docker:
  - image: elasticsearch:1.3.9
  - image: circleci/mysql:5.6
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: true
      MYSQL_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: %
      MYSQL_DATABASE: MyDB
environment:
  SBT_VERSION: 1.1.0
  SBT_OPTS: "-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M"
```

Comment: Hi there, do you know where I can find a list of existing keys and their meaning? thx.

Comment: Yup, the CircleCI Configuration Reference: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/